# Counting chars in a file | python 3x

Tags: python, counting, chars

I'm wondering, how can I count for example all "s" characters and print their number in a text file that I'm importing? Tried few times to do it by my own but I'm still doing something wrong. If someone could give me some tips I would really appreciate that :)

Comment: Please do show us your attempt; that way we don't have to cover ground you already know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file, the `"r"` means it is opened as readonly mode.

```
filetoread = open("./filename.txt", "r")
```

With this loop, you iterate over all the lines in the file and counts the number of times the character *chartosearch* appears. Finally, the value is printed.

```
total = 0
chartosearch = 's'
for line in filetoread:
    total += line.count(chartosearch)
print("Number of " + chartosearch + ": " + total)
```

Comment: Please also comment on the code to be more educative.

Comment: I thought that the code was self-explanatory, by the way, I added some.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to read a file, find the number of `s` s and then, store the result at the end of the file.

```
f = open('blah.txt','r+a')
data_to_read = f.read().strip()
total_s = sum(map(lambda x: x=='s', data_to_read ))
f.write(str(total_s))
f.close()
```

I did it functionally just to give you another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You open the file with an `open("myscript.txt", "r")` with the mode as `"r"` because you are reading. To remove whitespaces and `\n`'s, we do a `.read().split()`. Then, using a `for` loop, we loop over each individual character and check if it is an `'S'` or an `'s'`, and each time we find one, we add one to the `scount` variable (`scount` is supposed to mean S-count).

```
filetoread = open("foo.txt").read().split()
scount = 0
for k in ''.join(filetoread):
    if k.lower() == 's':
        scount+=1

print ("There are %d 's' characters" %(scount))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with a reasonable time performance (~500MB/s on my machine) for ascii letters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from functools import partial

byte = sys.argv[1].encode('ascii') # s
print(sum(chunk.count(byte)
          for chunk in iter(partial(sys.stdin.buffer.read, 1<<14), b'')))
```

Example:

```
$ echo baobab | ./count-byte b
3
```

It could be easily changed to support arbitrary Unicode codepoints:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from functools import partial

char = sys.argv[1]
print(sum(chunk.count(char)
          for chunk in iter(partial(sys.stdin.read, 1<<14), '')))
```

Example:

```
$ echo ⛄⛇⛄⛇⛄ | ./count-char ⛄
3
```

To use it with a file, you could use a redirect:

```
$ ./count-char < input_file
```